# How can I display "Recent actions" in my project

Tags: python, django

How can I display "Recent actions" in my project for a specific application like the one in Django Panel
For example, when adding a new product, deleting a product, or modifying a product

[image]
Is there a library to add this feature?

Comment: Create such "recent action" entries using the `LogEntry` model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/admin/#logentry-objects